# calendar.dateComponents returning negative value even though resultDate is after startDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatecomponents

I have the following code:

```
let utime = 1658885981959026
let utimeInSeconds = Double(utime/1000000)
let startDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: utimeInSeconds) // Start date - 2022-07-27 01:39:41 +0000 
let endDate = Date() // End date - 2022-07-27 18:33:14 +0000

let calendar = Calendar.current
let startDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour, .minute, .second], from: startDate)
let endDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour, .minute, .second], from: endDate)
let differenceDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour, .minute, .second], from: startDateComponents, to: endDateComponents)

print(differenceDateComponents.hour!, differenceDateComponents.minute!, differenceDateComponents.second!) // Prints -7 -6 -27
```

I'd expect the `.hour` value to be `16`, but I get a value of `-7` instead. Could someone help me understand why?

Note: Weirdly enough, if I run this in [Swift playground](http://online.swiftplayground.run/), it gives me the correct values.

Comment: Please add how you are making startDate and endDate.

Comment: If you set let now = Date(); let startDate = now.addingTimeInterval(-3600); let endDate = now it gives 1 0 0 which is correct.

Comment: @Asteroid I've update the code to reflect how I'm making `startDate` and `endDate`

Comment: You should use `func dateComponents(_ components: Set<Calendar.Component>, from start: Date, to end: Date) -> DateComponents` where `from`/`to` params are `Date`. Else, it's more "complicated" since you don't have really a "start point", but a "floating one", and I guess that's the issue...

Comment: @Larme That worked, thank you so much! Could you elaborate on what you mean by "you don't have really a "start point""? I'm trying to understand better what I was doing wrong. Also, do you know why it'd work in the Playground but not on Xcode?

Comment: Could you print `startDateComponents` & `endDateComponents`, and `Locale.current`, when it's not working? Since it's `01:39:41`, I'm wondering, if with your locale, when you get the components, it's not getting the day before, hence startDate if you only consider weekday fails... But if you date `startDateComponents` had `.day` instead of `.weekday`, which isn't clear why it's used for a comparison, then since you consider only these variables, `startDateComponents` is after `endDateComponents`